# Microsoft Graph API - 'AuthenticationError ' (HTTP 400) on calls for GET /users/<user_id>/mailFolders/inbox/messageRules

Tags: outlook, azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft-graph-api

We're running into an error with a specific Graph API endpoint, so any help or advice here is appreciated!

**Problem:**

We're seeing unexpected HTTP 400 errors on calls to fetch specific users' inbox rules, with code `AuthenticationError`.

**Request:**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<USER_ID>/mailFolders/inbox/messageRules
```

**Response:**

```
{
  "error": {
    "code":"AuthenticationError",
    "message":"Error authenticating with resource",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id":"44bbcef3-b8cd-4da0-978e-99955e55f3a7",
      "date":"2020-05-19T14:55:52"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that we're only calling this method for non-external users where `userType` is `member` and `onPremisesSyncEnabled` is `null`. We're also supplying each user's ID as a parameter, rather than their user principal name.

Also - this example was pulled from our application, which *is* able to make calls to other Graph API endpoints without issue, including calls to fetch Users, Groups, Domains/Organizations, etc. This method does work for most of our clients but is failing in a few particular cases.

Here is a list of application scopes granted for the client:

```
AccessReview.Read.All
AuditLog.Read.All
Contacts.Read
Directory.Read.All
EduAdministration.Read.All
Group.Read.All
IdentityRiskEvent.Read.All
IdentityRiskyUser.Read.All
MailboxSettings.Read
Member.Read.Hidden
ProgramControl.Read.All
Reports.Read.All
SecurityEvents.Read.All
Sites.Read.All
User.Read.All
```

If there's any additional information we can provide to make this easier to troubleshoot, just let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of permission are you using in Azure AD app? Delegated permission or Application Permission? And what value did you set for `scope` while calling the `/token` endpoint? Is it `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`? Please share your full request (include request body and response) of getting access token.

Comment: @AllenWu They're all application permissions with the exception of the default ```User.Read``` delegated permission.

Also, the value specified when calling `/token` is indeed `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`.

I'll update this comment w/ the request body/response info -- thanks!

Comment: I configured the same Application permissions as yours and it works fine for me. Have you tried to create a new Azure AD app and add only  `MailboxSettings.Read` permission in the app to test?